# computing hourly amplitude from coordinate time series

Tags: fft, amplitude

I have a coordinate time series for 2 hours and 1 second interval (observation=7200). How can I compute the hourly amplitude from this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data does not contain noise (You did not say nothing about it), then you can calculate amplitude very easy by using definition of amplitude:

```
A = (max(x) - min(x))/2, where x - your data
```

P.S.
If you are not satisfied with the answer, then you need to clarify your question. In particular - what signal and what you mean by amplitude and how you going to use this number